# How to make VS 2015 remember connection to TFS?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs

We recently started using TFS 2017 (on prem). Previously we were using TFS 2015 (on prem). Every time I start VS 2015, I have to go to the Manage Connections dialog in Team Explorer and re-connect to the new server. I used to not have to do this, as VS would reliably remember the connection.

There are others on my team who have this same issue, while others do not (i.e. their VS still automatically connects as always.)

Any advice on how to solve would be appreciated.

I found some things about how to turn this desired behavior OFF, involving registry settings. I will also point out that once you connect to the TFS, it stays connected... We don't have issues with it losing it after that.

Thanks,
Gerald

MORE INFO: We use Git source control. Our team project has several repositories. When VS starts, there is no connection to TFS. When I add one, with Manage Connections, it seems to pick a repo at random. Eventually by connecting/disconnecting/connecting it will present the desired repository and I can open our solution. Is there a way to tell it which repository to use, instead of it just picking one randomly?

After I connect to my team project, I see this:

[image: Team Explorer Connect]

Others have reported I should be seeing a list of local and remote repositories.

Comment: More info: our Team Project has several different repositories. When I connect to it with Manage Connections, I want to say there used to be a widget that would let me choose which repository... this seems to be missing now. In many cases it will try to connect to a repository that does not have the code for this particular solution... leaving me connected to TFS, but insisting that I clone a repository in order to open solutions. Which makes sense, except that I don't want to clone that repository, I want to connect to one that is already cloned...

Comment: Have you selected the remember credential when add the TFS server in VS? And have you ever changed the credential before?

Comment: I don't really see any place to tell TFS to remember the credential. I've only ever used the same credentials to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you close the VS with TFS connected, then it will automatically connect to the TFS when you start VS again.

Please try to remember credentials: [How can I make TFS remember my credentials when opening Visual Studio](http://kb.dynamsoft.com/questions/735/How+can+I+make+TFS+remember+my+credentials+when+opening+Visual+Studio), then check it again.

If that still not work, please try below things to narrow down the issue:

1. Close any opened VS instances, Clean VS caches (delete the files
   under below path), then start VS to reconnect the TFS.

   `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
   C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Team Explorer`
2. Reset the userdata, then connect to TFS again.

   `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
   devenv.exe /resetuserdata`

For the issue you mentioned in comment:

Seems it's related to workspace mapping. Just try to delete the existing workspace, then configure the workspace again. Or remapping the existing workspace to let the TFS identify it.

---

**UPDATE:**

For TFVC you need to navigate to Manage Workspace (Team Explorer > Solutions > Workspace > Manage Workspace) to remap the existing workspace. For Git you need to Clone the remote repository first. See [Get Started with Git and VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/git/gitquickstart?tabs=visual-studio) for details

Comment: Thanks for your response. Our ability to use credential manager is locked out by our systems admins. re #1: there is not a Team Explorer folder on my machine at that location. I did remove the other files in ComponentModelCache and reset user data as you suggested. Still does the same thing.

Comment: Are workspaces specific to TFVC? I should have pointed out that we use Git for version control.

Comment: @Gerald It's also available for Git. Just try to create a new repo to check that.

Comment: I feel like a moron, but I'm just not seeing anything about mapping workspaces when I do that. The only time I see anything about workspaces is when I connect to our TFS and don't pick a team project. This eventually opens up a "source code explorer" that shows the one and only TFVC project on our TFS. It points out that my local workspace is unmapped, so I map it to the folder on my local where I keep my source code. The end result is the same though.. next time I open my project in VS, it is not connected to TFS.

Comment: @Gerald For TFVC you need to navigate to **Manage Workspace**
 (Team Explorer > Solutions > Workspace > Manage Workspace) to remap the existing workspace. For Git  you need to Clone the remote repository first. See [Get Started with Git and VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/git/gitquickstart?tabs=visual-studio) for details.

Comment: I have read that article and following it (a couple of times so far) got me to where I am. I'm assuming that if I delete the local repository folder/files that is all that I need to do to remove anything "left over" that would be confusing the new clone. I'll give it another try today for good measure.